# Flow of App or program in Android

Tags: android

hi I am a newbie to android programming and I learnt many basic programs and now when I started studying some of the sample programs. I am getting confused about the flow of the program in the areas like one method calling another and so on,

Also I tried DEBUGGING but it didn't work fine as many of the apps need input from user for understanding the complete flow of the program

So is there a way such that newbies like me can first understand the flow of program then dig into the code written over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Android Activity Life cycle on the android developer site.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Let me know if you have any questions,I will be happy to help where I can.